# making new web application in sharepoint foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, iis-6, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have made a new web application on sharepoint foundation 2013 using the steps mentioned in link below.But when i try to access it using both server and client i get the message "401 UNAUTHORIZED".what to do?

http://sharepointgeorge.com/2012/create-web-application-site-collection-sharepoint-2013-preview/

I made it on a client pc having rights of administrator.I have tried quite a few thing by changing iis settings but this problem is not getting solved.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have kerberos enabled in this environment?  If it's not configured correctly, this behavior can happen.  You might check your logs to see if there is any additional information.